# Converting a string of list to list in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas column whose values are list of words. But the whole list is datatype string.

For example one cell value of this column is

```
 a=   ['expert executive', 'internal committee period', 'report name', 'entry']

type(a)
Out[23]:
str
```

But this is stored as string.

Now issue is I want to access this value as a list as I want to use list operation of extending this list with another list. However since currently it is typed as string, list operations doesn't work on this.

Any idea how can I access this value as list instead of string. I tried doing list(a), it will break it all down to individual character since whole a is a string.

Comment: import ast ,  then apply(ast.literal_eval)

Answer (score 1):

Use the **ast module**.

**Ex:**

```
import ast
import pandas as pd
l =   "['expert executive', 'internal committee period', 'report name', 'entry']"
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [l]})
print(type(df["a"][0]))
df["a"]  = df["a"].apply(ast.literal_eval)
print(type(df["a"][0]))
```

**Output:**

```
<type 'str'>
<type 'list'>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    a=   ['expert executive', 'internal committee period', 'report name', 'entry']
    c=list(a)
    type(c)
```

out[1]:
        list

```
    c[1]
```

out[2]: expert executive

> update your python , you should not even need the casting c=list(a). because your code

```
    a=   ['expert executive', 'internal committee period', 'report name', 'entry']
```

> is working as a list for me ,fine

Comment: but if you have the list as a=   ' ['expert executive', 'internal committee period', 'report name', 'entry'] ' ? then it would be different story . do you have it like in this comment ?

Comment: its a string. If you do list it would extract out each character